# In javascript- save variable as a reference

Tags: javascript, object, pass-by-reference

```
var foo = {prop:1};
var bar = {prop:2};
var obj = {};
obj[foo] = 'value';
console.log(obj[bar]); //'value'
```

It is quite confusing why `obj[bar]` and `obj[foo]` are same now, whereas `foo` and `bar` are not same.

Comment: Hacketo has provided the correct answer. Also see [MDN: Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) for more information.

Comment: It's also here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors under "Property names"

Answer (score 8):

because

```
obj[foo]='value';
```

is the same as

```
obj["[object Object]"]='value';
```

Object keys are string so it's internally doing `foo.toString()`

and `foo.toString() === bar.toString()`

Every objects will return `"[object Object]"` if used as a key (not talking about arrays, numbers, strings..)

---

You'll need something that uniquely identify your objects, like below

```
var foo = {id:"foo", prop:1};
var bar = {id:"bar", prop:2};
var obj = {};
obj[foo.id] = 'value';
console.log(obj[bar.id]); //undefined
```

Comment: Its a implicit behaviour `obj[foo]` is doing `obj[foo.toString()]`

Comment: I will create a new object -
`var cc= new Object()`
then `console.log(obj[cc]);`  `//value`
Conclusion: here object `cc`  will be converted to `"[object Object]"`.
here if I will look `obj` in console-
`Object {[object Object]: "value"}`

Comment: @jiten as stated in my answer